# Error al enviar datos por ajax al controlador

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Mi función llamada registrar no envia los datos al controlador pese a que todo esta bien, solo me devuelve error, pero como es posible? si en la condición le digo, si el campo esta vacio me retorne error, pero no esta vacio me deberia retornar el mensaje "exito",Que estoy haciendo mal??

```
$(function () {
    $("#btn-registrar").on('click',  function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var _form = $("#form-Registrar");
        if (_form.find('#nombres').val()==='') {
            return false;
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: baseURL +'usuario/registrar',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: _form.serializeArray(),
        }) .done(function(response) {
            if (Boolean(response.status)===true) {
                //loadURL(baseURL+'marcas/list_marcas');
                alert("exito");
            }else{
                alert(response.message);
            }
        }).fail(function(response) {
            console.log("error",response);
        })
    });
});
```

Aquí el controlador:

```
<?php class Usuario extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Model_Usuario');
    }

    public function index(){
        $data['contenido']="usuario/index";
        //$data['contenido']="usuario/index";//enviar a plantilla la vista
        $data['selPerfil']=$this->Model_Usuario->selPerfil();
        $this->load->view("plantilla",$data);//cargamos la plantilla
    }

    public function registrar(){
         echo "sadsa";
    }
}?>
```

Aquí las vistas:

```
<h1>FORMULARIO DE REGISTRO</h1>
<form id="form-Registrar">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Nombres</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombres" placeholder="Nombres">
    </div>
    <button id="btn-registrar" type="submit" name="werwrw" class="btn btn-default">Registrar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Después de evaluar y analizar el código con el `var_dump`   el problema era que al utilizar el ajax de jquery y al especificar el parametro url, el cual va a tener de destino nuestro controlador,, este controlador debe estar implementado , ya que ajax establece una comunicación bidireccional con  este y lo otro era que no estaba recogiendo los valores adecuadamente enla vista, Publico el codigo funcionando al 100%

```js
$(function() {

  $("#btn-registrar").on('click',  function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var _form = $("#form-Registrar");

    if (_form.find('#id').val()==='') {
      alert("Ingrese id");
  
        return false;
    };
    
    if (_form.find('#nombres').val()==='') {
      alert("Ingrese Nombre");

        return false;
    };

  
    $.ajax({
      url: baseURL +'usuario/registrar',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: _form.serializeArray(),
    })
    .done(function(response) {

      if (Boolean(response.status)===true) {
      //  loadURL(baseURL+'marcas/list_marcas');
        alert("exito");
      }else{
        alert(response.message);

      }
    })
    .fail(function(response) {
      console.log("error",response);
    })


  });



 });
```

```html
<h1>FORMULARIO DE REGISTRO</h1>
<form id="form-Registrar">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">id</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="id" placeholder="id">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Nombres</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name ="nombres" placeholder="Nombres">
  </div>

  <button id="btn-registrar"  name="werwrw" class="btn btn-default">Registrar</button>
</form>
```

Esta es el Controller

```
 <?php
class Usuario extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

      $this->load->model('Model_Usuario');

}

  public function index(){

    $data['contenido']="usuario/index";
    //  $data['contenido']="usuario/index";//enviar a plantilla la vista
      $data['selPerfil']=$this->Model_Usuario->selPerfil();

      $this->load->view("plantilla",$data);//cargamos la plantilla
}



public function registrar(){

    $_name = $this->input->post('nombres',true);

            if ($_name==='')
                 exit(json_encode(array('status'=>false,'id'=>'nombres')));

    $_des = $this->input->post('id',true);
                         if ($_des==='')
                              exit(json_encode(array('status'=>false,'id'=>'id')));

    $_input = $this->input->post();

            if ($this->Model_Usuario->addMarca( $_input ))

                exit(json_encode(array('status'=>true,'message'=>'Marca registrada')));
            else
                exit(json_encode(array('status'=>false,'message'=>'Error al  registrar')));

}




}


 ?>
```

Este es el Modelo

```
 <?php
class Model_Usuario extends CI_Model{

  function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();

  }

    public function selPerfil(){
      $query="select * from perfil ";
      $result = $this->db->query($query);
      return $result->result();


  }


  public function addMarca( $_input) {
    $datos=array(
      'per_id'=>$_input['id'],
       'per_nombre'=>$_input['nombres'],


        );

    if ( $this->db->insert('perfil',$datos))
        return true;


    return false;




}

}
```

Comment: Podrias aceptar esta respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error se debe a que no tienes la extension del archivo, intenta asi:

```
url: baseURL +'usuario/registrar.php',
```

espero te sirva, me cuentas...

Comment: Ya lo probe y en el debug del firefox si pongo la extension .php no encuentra la url,,, la sintaxis es controlador/ funcion.}

Comment: estas usando motos de plantillas ? como blade o algo asi ?

Comment: no,solo boostrap

Comment: entonces, el problema es de rutas, ya que laravel maje rutas, debes mirar su ya estan definidas